# Solving underdetermined Lyapunov equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm solving the following for $X$ with $A,B$ singular positive semidefinite matrices.

$$AX + XA = B$$

Because $A$, $B$ are singular, standard Lyapunov solver fails

However, if I heuristically skip dividing by 0 elements in Matlab [implementation](https://github.com/msubhransu/matrix-sqrt/blob/master/lyap2.m) of the Lyapunov solver, I get the same answer as the least squares solution to $(A\otimes I + I\otimes A)\operatorname{vec}X=\operatorname{vec}B$

Does this appear in the literature, or does someone see a way to prove that this works?

(originally [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808422/least-squares-solution-to-underdetermined-lyapunov-equation) on math.SE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric, it has an eigendecomposition $A = QDQ^*$ with $Q$ orthogonal. Then
$$
M = A \otimes I + I\otimes A = (Q\otimes Q)(D\otimes I + I \otimes D)(Q\otimes Q)^*
$$
is an eigendecomposition and also a singular value decomposition. The standard formula for the pseudoinverse in terms of the SVD gives
$$
M^+ = (A \otimes I + I\otimes A)^+ = (Q\otimes Q)(D\otimes I + I \otimes D)^+(Q\otimes Q)^*,
$$
where the pseudoinverse in the middle is a diagonal matrix with elements $\frac{1}{d_i+d_j}$ if $d_i+d_j\neq 0$ or $0$ otherwise.

Your implementation computes the minimum-norm least-squares solution $\operatorname{vec}X = M^+\operatorname{vec} B$ with this formula, if I am not mistaken.

Note also that in your case the explicit inverse `IT` can be avoided, since `T` ($Q$ above) is orthogonal.